# Craft 3 front end form file uploads not saving if filename exists?

Tags: assets, craft3, frontend-form

I have a front end save entry form which users can attach photos too, it all works fine unless a photo with the same filename is saved, in this instance the entry saves but the asset field is just left blank, can't find anything in the docs,

Any help or a point in the right direction appreciated!

```
<form id="addCompanyForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  {{ csrfInput() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="7">
  <input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/save-entry">

  <input id="title" type="text" name="title">
  <input id="companyLogo" type="file" name="fields[companyLogo]" accept=".png, .jpg">

  </form>
```

Comment: Do you use a custom controller for it or the default craft way?

Comment: @RobinSchambach default craft way, have updated original Q with the form code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug. The Asset wasn't saved because it would not be validated due to conflicting filenames. Thankfully, it's [fixed now](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/8ca98621a49f2650ee0f15ae9dc6a6fb1c9df145).